# React Query "Fetching" state but not sending request to server

Tags: reactjs

I'm having a recurrent problem with react query. On some queries, the query says "fetching" (blue color), but the request to the server "doesn't go through". It's "suspended" or something. And I tried console.logging on my nodeJS controller (associated with the GET endpoint), but the function isn't even called.

This is quite annoying (and to be clear, this is with new queries which aren't stale or cached).

This is my query:

```
const postDetails = useQuery(
    ["post", postId],
    async () =>
      await fetch(
        "http://localhost:5000/api/post/id/" + postId
      ).then((res) => res.json()),
    {
      onSuccess: (data) => {
        console.log(data);
      },
    }
  );
```

This is what React Query Devtools says:

[image]

This is what the network tab says:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you are mixing 2 different asynchronous promise syntaxes.  I would recommend using `.then` OR `await`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your use of `await` and `.then` is giving you issues.  I would recommend just sticking with `await`

```
const postDetails = useQuery(
    ["post", postId],
    async () =>
      try {
        let res = await fetch(
          "http://localhost:5000/api/post/id/" + postId
        )
        res = await res.json()
      } catch(err) {
        console.error(err)
      }
    {
      onSuccess: (data) => {
        console.log(data);
      },
    }
  );
```

This method uses a `trycatch` for error handling, and does not rely on `.then` which I believe is where the issue lies.

Comment: `res.json()`is also a promise. Also need an await: `res = await res.json()`

Comment: I tried your way but it's not working. Even removing async/await does not. One thing I noticed though, is that if I go directly to the post route it works fine, it's when I get to the route from another page that it doesn't work. Can't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Try separating the fetch function from the query:

```js
async function fetchPosts() {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(
      "http://localhost:5000/api/post/id/" + postId
    )
    const json = await res.json()
    return json
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
}
const postDetails = useQuery(
  ["post", postId],
  fetchPosts,
  {
    onSuccess: (data) => {
      console.log(data);
    },
  }
);
```

Comment: Still not working, unfortunately. 
It works when I go directly to the post route on the browser, but if I get there through <Link> that's when the request seems broken. Sometimes it fetches, most of the time it doesn't.

I suppose that's because by going directly to the URL, the react query cache gets reset and so the request has to be made to the server, but with <Link>, it's as if it tries to fetch from the cache, but the data is obviously not there. Weird.

Comment: Do you get any error in your client/backend side?

Comment: No errors, I just get back "undefined" if I console log the postDetails.